# How do I print out Integeral values in haskell without warning using show?

Tags: haskell, warnings, show, ghci, integral

When I run the following haskell code with warnings enabled

```
module Main where
main :: IO()
main = interact (unlines.strout.calc.extinps.words)

--calculates factorial
factorial :: Integral a=> a->a
factorial n = product [1..n]

--Extracts numbers from the input
extinps ::(Read b)=>[String]->[b]
extinps x=map read x

--Calculates the factorial
calc :: (Integral b) => [b] -> [b]
calc x= map factorial x

--Converts the result to a string
strout::(Show b)=>[b]->[[Char]]
strout x=[show a|a<-x]
```

I get the warning following warning:

```
factout.hs:3:26: Warning:
Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `Integer'
   (Show b0) arising from a use of `strout' at factout.hs:3:26-31
   (Read b0) arising from a use of `extinps' at factout.hs:3:38-44
   (Integral b0) arising from a use of `calc' at factout.hs:3:33-36    
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `strout'                       
In the second argument of `(.)', namely                                 
   `strout . calc . extinps . words'                                   
In the first argument of `interact', namely                               
   `( unlines . strout . calc . extinps . words)'
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

How do I get rid of the it?

Comment: Oh lol, I'm silly I thought you just wanted a way to disable the warning. My bad.

Comment: BTW can be simplified with `map g . map f = map (g . f)`; `strout` is a third `map`. With `main = interact (unlines . map (show . factorial . read) . words` 3 helper functions can be removed.

Comment: `-fno-warn-type-defaults`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know which concrete implementation of `Integral` it should use. It *guesses* `Integer` would be ok.

If you annotate e.g. `calc`, the warning will go away:

```
main :: IO ()
main = interact (unlines . strout . (calc :: [Integer] -> [Integer]) . extinps . words)
```